# Compact subset continuity

Tags: metric-spaces

Can someone help me with this? it seems really easy question but i couldn't see it through...

For a compact Subset $K$ of a metric space $X$ and $x \in X$. The Function is $f:X\to R$ given by $f(x) = d(x,K)$.

Show that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in X$, let's show that f is continuous in $x$. Let $t \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ By definition of $d$, $\exists a \in K$ such as, $d(x,a) \le d(x,K) + \epsilon$. So $d(t,K) \le d(t,x) + d(x,a) \le d(t,x) + d(x,K) + \epsilon$. So $f(t) \le d(t,x) + f(x) + \epsilon$, if we make $\epsilon$ tends to $0$, we have $f(t) \le f(x) + d(t,x)$.

With the same reasonning we have $f(x) \le f(t) + d(t,x)$. So $|f(x)-f(t)| \le d(x,t)$, so $f$ is 1-lipschitz, so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: i almost got it but how do you say $$ d(x,a) \le d(x,K) + e $$

Comment: $d(x,K)=inf(d(x,k)|k \in K)$, so you you obtain the inegality by definition of the infinum. So if you fix the $\epsilon$, you can find $a \in K$ such as $d(x,a)$ is small enough to fit in the inequality.

Comment: Now i get it. thank you Jennifer! :)